# Почему props лучше state?

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS пропагандирует предпочтительное использование `props`. Но единственный способ внести изменения в такое приложение, это пересоздание `props`. Когда данных на странице не много, это выглядит нормальным. Но когда надо редактировать огромные таблицы...

объясните, пожалуйста,

почему обновление данных через `actions`:

```
var addPhone = function (phone) {
  return {
    type: "ADD_PHONE",
    phone
  }
};
var deletePhone = function (phone) {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_PHONE",
    phone
  }
};

module.exports = {addPhone, deletePhone};
```

...

```
var Map = require("immutable").Map;

var reducer = function(state = Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_STATE":
        return state.merge(action.state);
    case "ADD_PHONE":
        return state.update("phones", (phones) => phones.push(action.phone));
    case "DELETE_PHONE":
        return state.update("phones",
            (phones) => phones.filterNot(
                (item) => item === action.phone
            )
        );
  }
  return state;
}
module.exports = reducer;
```

лучше чем редактирование `state`:

```
this.state.phones[i] = phone;
this.forceUpdate();
```

Comment: Props - часть публичного интерфейса, state - детали внутренней реализации. Снаружи (а моделька - это снаружи для вашей вьюхи) лезть в детали реализации - порочная практика. Так яснее?

Comment: В общем сверху у вас написана манипуляция абстракцией отвечающей за модель данных приложения. Снизу - такой абстракции нету и с внешним миром мы не общаемся. У каждой абстракции есть цена, но конкретно эта - очень удобна в больших приложениях.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, тоесть `props` удобней по идеологическим соображением, и за это мы готовы жертвовать производительностью?

Comment: да. Если у нас возникает узкое место по производительности мы можем чуть подрасплести абстракции и подпереть там и тут.

Comment: Также надо возникать что реально узкие места в производительности реальных приложений и самые кошмарные баги возникают просто потому что разработчик не понял и нахреначил ужас-ужас. Хорошая идеологически верная структура приложения от такого как раз более-менее защищает.

Comment: Собственно развитие программирования оно в основном так и происходит. Появляется удобная абстракция, но в ущерб которой приходится слегка жертвовать перформансом. Со временем она выглаживается до того что потери производительности минимальны, или исчезает за ненадобностью. Вы же не в машинных кодах сайты пишете.